# How to add class to bbPress bbp_get_topic_author_link()?

Tags: bbpress

How can I add a class with `bbp_get_topic_author_link()` function.

I want to add a class in the image, am trying  to do like below:

```
   <?php 
      printf( 
      bbp_get_topic_author_link( 

        array( 
          'type' => 'avatar', 
          'size' => '75',
          'class' => 'my-class-goes-here'
       ) 

     )

    ) ; ?>
```

But still not working.

Comment: It's not easy to comment, I don't have bbPress installed. The [core code](https://github.com/wp-plugins/bbpress/blob/2.5.8/includes/topics/template.php#L1529) does _NOT_ have an `$args` variable with the key 'class' is passed. You can use the filter hook `bbp_get_topic_author_link` and can `preg_replace()` with a valid regex if the first argument `$author_link` is an HTML string.

Comment: Would you mind to answer the question with the code?

Comment: for example  : $author_link = bbp_get_topic_author_link(array('post_id' => $topic_id, 'type' => 'both', 'size' => 14));
  echo "<span class='topic-author'>"  . $author_link . "</span>";